# MongoDB 14.3k documents .find() take too long to load

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, find

My MongoDB database is hosted in MongoDB Atlas with version 4.4.

I have dynamic `Text` collections based on some linked information, e.g. `project_a_texts` or `project_b_texts`. The documents look like the following:

```
[{
  "_id": ObjectId(''),
  "status": 1|0,
  "schemaVersion": number,
  "createdBy": ObjectId(''),
  "key": string,
  "history": [
    {
      "valueType": string,
      "_id": ObjectId(''),
      "value": string,
      "author": ObjectId(''),
      "authorName": string,
      "createdAt": Date,
      "updatedAt": Date
    }
  ],
  "value": {
    "valueType": string,
    "_id": ObjectId(''),
    "value": string,
    "author": ObjectId(''),
    "authorName": string,
    "createdAt": Date,
    "updatedAt": Date
  },
  "createdAt": Date,
  "updatedAt": Date,
  "__v": number
}]
```

I generate the following indexes In mongoose:

```
const texts = mongoose.Schema({
  ...schema
}, {
  timestamps: true,
  autoCreate: true,
  autoIndex: true,
});

texts.index({ status: 1 });
```

When I use `.find()` in the collections it works fast, except for one collection that is reaching now 14.3k documents. Using Postman, that query takes on average **7 seconds** in production, and between 500ms - 2s in local. The rest of the collections don't even reach 5k. The query looks like this:

```
const response = await collection.find({
    status: 1
  }, {
    _id: 0,
    key: 1,
    'value.value': 1,
});
```

The vast majority of the documents in that problematic collection have `status` value set to `1`, so the query returns around 14.1k results. Because of how the application that consumes that data has been setup, I need to query all those in one go, and there is no option to make the query more selective (using `$text` search in text indexes).

When I run the `executionStats`, the number of documents scanned is the same of number returned.

Is it normal that it takes that amount of time? Is there anything I can do to improve the response time?

Also I feel the difference between production environment and local it's too significant? The RestAPIs are hosted in Azure, node version 14.

Comment: How large are the documents? What is the ping (network) time between the app and the database? What size server is the database running on? In any case, you'd probably be better off dropping that index since the [query is _not_ selective](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/create-queries-that-ensure-selectivity/) so it is probably slowing down execution.